# Putting NSMutableAttributedString with font and size into UIPasteboard to paste into another app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipasteboard

I have to copy a string along with a font and particular size. I have converted it into a `NSMutableAttributedString` with all Property like font and size but can't copy it into `UIPasteBoard`.

I tried to convert it into RTF data and then encoded it, but it all fails.

This is my code for the same:

```
NSRange attRange = NSMakeRange(0, [textString length]);
attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:textString];
    [attString  addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:[fontsArray objectAtIndex:index] size:12] range:attRange];
NSData *data = [attString dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [attString length]) documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFTextDocumentType} error:nil];

UIPasteboard *paste = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
paste.items = @[@{(id)kUTTypeRTFD: [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],(id)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText: attString.string}];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
```

**Copy** `NSAttributedString` in ios

```
  NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

  NSData *rtf = [attributedString dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)
                             documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFDTextDocumentType}
                                          error:nil];

  if (rtf) {
    [item setObject:rtf forKey:(id)kUTTypeFlatRTFD];
  }

  [item setObject:attributedString.string forKey:(id)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];

  UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  pasteboard.items = @[item];
```

**Paste** `NSAttributedString` in ios

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString;

    NSData* rtfData = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] dataForPasteboardType:(id)kUTTypeFlatRTFD];

    if (rtfData) {
        attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:rtfData options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFDTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    _lblResult.attributedText=attributedString;
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: check this now ,

Comment: In the nsdictionary you are adding two object.. one is rtf and other is string.. and the uipasteboard uses the string..

Comment: Yes , rtf is the font

Comment: have you used it to copy formatted text??? coz when i used this code.. it only paste string without font..

Comment: and if you can see my question,  I've also done in the same way.

Comment: i have done copy and Pasting AttributedString within app , And i think if you want to Paste in other apps , that depends on other app weather they app support atrributed Text or not.

if You want to paste within app than , i can post my `pasting` code ...

Comment: i got it bro... i was not aware of this logic that the third app should also 
 have to support the attributted string.. thanks for the rply

Answer (score 0):

I had an `NSAttributedString` in a Swift Playground I needed to get onto the clipboard, and I converted this code to Swift to do it. In case someone else is here for the same thing:

```
import MobileCoreServices // defines the UTType constants

// UIPasteboard expects Dictionary<String,Any>, so either use
// explicit type in the definition or downcast it like I have.
var item = [kUTTypeUTF8PlainText as String : attributedString.string as Any]

if let rtf = try? attributedString.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, 
    attributedString.length), documentAttributes: 
    [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSRTFDTextDocumentType]) {
    // The UTType constants are CFStrings that have to be
    // downcast explicitly to String (which is one reason I
    // defined item with a downcast in the first place)
      item[kUTTypeFlatRTFD as String] = rtf
}

UIPasteboard.general.items = [item]
```

Comment: When i paste it's paste simple font